# Breakpoints for assembly code in VSCode with GDB

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, gdb, x86-64, att

I use xUbuntu 22.04.4 and the VSCode current version for linux (1.87.2)

I want to set the debugging of a `.s` assembly (AT&T) file. I created a `task.json` and a `launch.json` file and allowed breakpoints everywhere in the settings.

When I launch the debugging, it is working, but the breakpoint is not taken into account. What can I change in my `task.json` and `launch.json` files (see code below)?

#### launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-nostdlib",   // Ne pas utiliser la bibliothèque standard
                "-o",          // Spécifie le nom du fichier de sortie
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",     // Nom du fichier de sortie
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.s" // Chemin vers le fichier source
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "pattern": {
                  "regexp": "error"
                }
              },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "focus": true,
                "clear": true
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I missed the `-g` argument in the `"args"` key in `task.json`:

```
       "args": [
                "-g", 
                "-nostdlib", // ....
```

in order to create debugging information for asm source line numbers.

Without that, only disassembly mode would work, and setting breakpoints by address like `b *0x400010` with an address copy/pasted from GDB `disas` output.